# Bring back Process list for VSCommand Attach to IIS button

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I tick `Automatic attach to all ...` and now this Process list disappear. How do I bring it back for VSCommand in VS2013 ?

[image: VScommand process list]

Answer (score 1):

While pressing the "Attach to IIS" press Ctrl + Shift. It will bring back the dialog.